# why is data initially re-renders with empty and then displaying my productdetails page with delay while routing? used useCallback & useMemo

Tags: reactjs

This is my code. By using useCallback and useMemo  the initial empty re render is not controlled. Initially empty data gets rendered ,after routing the same product get replaced with the selected product.

Routing component

```
  <Header/>
     <Routes>
        <Route  path="/"  element={<ProductListing/>} />
        <Route exact path="/product/:productId" element={<ProductDetail/>} />
        <Route>404 Not Found!</Route>
     </Routes> 
     <Link to={`/product/${id}`}>`
    ...
```

```
  const product = useSelector((state) => state.product);
  const { productId } = useParams();
  console.log(productId);
    
  const {  title, image, price, category ,description} = product;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  console.log(product);

  const fetchProductDetail = async (id) => {
     const response = await axios
        .get(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${id}`)
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Err: ", err);
        });
     dispatch(selectedProducts(response.data));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
     if (productId && productId !== "") fetchProductDetail(productId);
     return () => {
         dispatch(removeSelectedProducts());
     };
  }, [productId]);
```

please resolve the issue

Comment: As far as, I have seen, Everything here seems to be working fine. Since you are getting datas delayed. Check whether you are getting datas faster from api call. If the particular api call returns response slowly. Then there might be a chance that your data will be populated slowly.